# i use the NG-cordova Geolocation plugin

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, gps

The Gps work fine and also the error event is caught great, BUT i want that if the user dont have the GPS enable so the GPS service confirmation pop up will shown and the user can click on the settings and redirect to the setting of the device

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
               marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
                    icon:'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png',
                    draggable:true,
                    map: map,
                    title: "My Location"
                });
               console.log(marker.getPosition().A);
               console.log(marker.getPosition().F);
                infoWindow.setContent('<div><strong>'+ "You are here!!" + '</strong><br>');
         infoWindow.open(map, marker);
             },
             function onError(error){
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "GPS is Disable Please Enable it.",
                        template: "Go to setting and turn it ON"
                    })
                    .then(function(result) {
                        if(result) {
                            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
                           // ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                        }
                    });
             },{maximumAge:60000,timeout:3000,enableHighAccuracy:false});
```

Comment: so what is the problem? when the error event is caught you are calling $ionicPopup which part is not working?

Comment: ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
    at map.js:85
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:21888)
    at ionic.bundle.js:21904
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:22916)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23205)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
    at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863)
    at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852)

Comment: this onecordova.plugins.diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings()